# Car stolen fully comp but SDP on my policy now Go Skippy won't pay out

Tags: united-kingdom, car-insurance

I am fully comp with Go Skippy, but on my policy it states [SDP](https://goskippy.com/2015/01/23/what-are-classes-of-use/).

I got called in to work last minute (at a supermarket).  So I drove, which I don't usually as I catch a lift with a friend.  When I was there I had my car stolen.  But now Go Skippy won't pay out because it was at my place of work.  So I'm stuck with 7k finance and no car.

Is there anything I can do or any advice please?  I can prove by work rotas that it was not my usual shift I was working.

Comment: Not familiar in the least with UK insurance law, but that sure sucks. Hopefully your car is found unharmed!

Comment: Someone else appears to have gone through a [similar experience with the same insurer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/81030/car-insurance-uk-excludes-commute-to-and-from-work-will-not-pay-on-claim-duri).

Comment: I'm not a lawyer but if your insurance is explicitly not valid for commuting to work and you drove your car to get to work ... I'd say you're out of luck. It doesn't matter why you drove to work or how rare an occurrence it was.

Answer (score 4):

It may be that you won't be able to get this reversed, but:

1. First, read the small-print of your contract to see exactly what Go Skippy's definitions of *Social, Domestic and Pleasure* (SDP) and *Social, Domestic, Pleasure and Commuting* (SDPC) say, if anything, about an isolated commute.

   I would particularly be on the look-out for something in the SDPC terms that talks of it covering "*regular commuting*" (so that, by implication, and unless specifically excluded in the SDP terms, a "one off" commute might arguably be covered by an SDP policy).
2. In the first instance, go through any appeals procedure Go Skippy have in place. Especially if the result of (1) is positive, you *may* be able to reverse the decision when it is looked at a second time (but equally, they may still reject it).

   Keep communication calm and focused: don't rant or get angry; state your case clearly. Keep copies of anything you send and their replies (do this by email or in writing).
3. Contact the [Financial Ombudsman Service](http://www.financial-ombudsman.org.uk/). They:

   > ...were set up by Parliament to resolve individual complaints between financial businesses and their customers. We can look into problems involving most types of money matters - from payday loans to pensions, pet insurance to PPI. If we decide someone's been treated unfairly, we have legal powers to put things right.

   But you must have tried to resolve the issue with the company concerned before contacting them. Have copies of all correspondence with Go Skippy ready.